# Javascript OOP Event Handlers not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eventhandler

I have an issue with an event handler in Javascript. I'm using an event handler to set the colour of a div. However, I have followed the already answered question on here:

```
// Add an event listener
document.addEventListener("name-of-event", function(e) {
console.log(e.detail); // Prints "Example of an event"
});

// Create the event
var event = new CustomEvent("name-of-event", { "detail": "Example of an       event" });

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

But it doesn't work for what I am trying to do. The bottom function is ran from an onclick event in the HTML document.

```
var colour = "#808080";
var event = new CustomEvent("set",{});

document.addEventListener("set", function (colour) {
    document.getElementById("light1").style.backgroundColor = colour;
});

//function that sets the colour variable to red and then triggers the event      handler, passing the colour variable
function setlight1red() {
    colour = "#ff0000"
    document.dispatchEvent(event, [colour]);
}
```

Appreciate any help, this does not return an error but just does not change the colour of the div when I run the .html file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
document.addEventListener("set", function (e) {
    document.getElementById("light1").style.backgroundColor = e.detail.color;
});

function setlight1red() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("set", {'detail': {color: "#ff0000"}}));
}
```

performance improvements:

If your color is static and will never be changed cache event and move it out of `setlight1red` function.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped. I now understand where I was going wrong.